# Creating Prompt for for non missing variable

Tags: macros, sas

I have a table created in a macro code. With this table I need to create a prompt. For creating prompt I have another macro at the second part. How can I combine these two code. It gives error. Says data Is not exist:

```
%macro bygroup(y);
  data recommendations_macro;
    set recommendations (where=(maingroup=&y));
  run;

  data issues_macro;
    set issues (where=(maingroup=&y));
  run;

  proc sort data=recommendations_macro (drop=issue);
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
  run;

  proc sort data=issues_macro (drop=Recommendation    );
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
  run;

  data rec_and_issues  ;
    merge recommendations_macro (in=a)
      issues_macro (in=b);
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
    if a or b;
  run;
%mend;
```

Created the table in here, I need to add this then:

```
%macro missing_or_nonmissing(sel=);
  %let not = %sysfunc(ifc(&sel=NonMissing,not,));

  SVFDBK_FEEDBACK_COMMENTS is &not. null
%mend missing_or_nonmissing;

DATA rec_and_issues;
  set rec_and_issues;
  where %missing_or_nonmissing(sel=&sel_issue) ;
run;

proc sort data=rec_and_issues (where=(%missing_or_nonmissing(sel=&sel_issue.)));
  by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM;
run;
```

Comment: Follow up question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295411/creating-prompt-for-missing-and-nonmissing  ?

Comment: Could you add the code you ran? And the exact error message returned? You said 'data is not exist', which dataset is that referring to?

Comment: I used the same code as you see, first one after another. Then the error "ERROR: File WORK.REC_AND_ISSUES.DATA does not exist."Thanks

Comment: You've created the macro `%bygroup`, have you called it anywhere after creating it? You'd call it by having a line like `%bygroup(test)`, where `test` would be a valid value of `maingroup`. If the `%bygroup` macro isn't run (or fails), then the `rec_and_issues` table is not created.

Comment: Sorry, you'd call it by running `%bygroup('test')`, assuming `maingroup` is a character variable.

Comment: First part's code is working, I need to add the second part. My macro knowledge is not good, so trying to understand. I don't know if I delete the %bygroup part, how I can create recommendations and issues table.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the update, indentation helps with readability of code. I think I know what you mean now. The first part of the code in your question, if run exactly as specified, will work, but it doesn't *do* anything because it is just a macro definition. To create `recommendations_macro` and `issues_macro`, you have to include a statement like: `%bygroup('maingrp')`, replacing maingrp with a valid `maingroup` value. This statement goes after the `%mend;` statement.

Comment: can you write the code as the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
%macro bygroup(y);
  proc sort data=recommendations (where=(maingroup=&y) drop=issue) 
       out=recommendations_macro;
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
  run;

  proc sort data=issues (where=(maingroup=&y) drop=recommendation)
            out=issues_macro;
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
  run;

  data rec_and_issues  ;
    merge recommendations_macro (in=a)
          issues_macro (in=b);
    by SFVFDBK_STUDENT_PIDM count;
    if a or b;
  run;
%mend;

%bygroup('hello')
```

I would also change the `where=` dataset option to match the type of column for maingroup. e.g.

if character:

`where maingroup="&y"`

if numeric:

`where maingroup=&y`

That way the macro call can be simplified to just:

`%bygroup(test)`

or

`%bygroup(3)`

respectively

Comment: At minimum, do those where statements in the PROC SORT - no reason to have those data steps in addition.

Comment: Agreed @Joe, I would usually use `PROC SQL` in all honestly, but it sometimes helps to improve code step-by-step for illustrative purposes.